# Can I Import any 3D.js Graph to React?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, data-visualization

I have some very complex graphs (for industry) to do with D3.js.

These graphs must be integrated into a web-app. I decided to use react due to it's scalability.

The app consists of only 5 pages for now. it might scale up to 20 in the future.

What should I do ?

Comment: D3.js is not the library to work with 3D object, maybe you mean to combine D3.js with [three.js](https://threejs.org/) and react, [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/81qjyxonm8?from-embed).

Comment: I haven't mentioned 3D objects at all :D the graphs are 2 dimentional but extremly complex.

They visualize data coming from sensors in the production chain of a factory

Comment: I don't know why sometimes I see D3 like 3D :'( my bad my friend! but from experience you try to avoid doing too much visualization with D3.js if your app built using React.js I have exactly the same case for airport system we built everything using D3.js and React, its bad for performance specially if you have SVG heavy graphics! if you can convert your graphs to canvas go with it!

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of blog posts out there that talk about integrating D3 with React directly, but in my experience I've found that just learning how to use the D3 scale functions directly, and then rendering your own svg elements is much easier to follow. For example, here is a relatively simple chart using a nice middleground of React and D3:

```
import {scaleTime} from "d3";

const width = 500;
const height = 300;
const date = [
  {date: new Date(2012,4,5), value: 5},
  {date: new Date(2013,3,2), value: 2},
  {date: new Date(2017,3,2), value: 7},
];

const MyChart = () => {
  const xScale = useMemo(() => {
    return scaleTime()
      .domain([new Date(2010,0,1), new Date(2020,0,1)])
      .range([0, width]);
  }, []);

  const yScale = useMemo(() => {
    return scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 10])
      .domain([height, 0]);
  }, []);

return (
  <svg width={width} height={height}>
    <line className="x-axis" x1={0} x2={width} y1={yScale(0)} y1={yScale(0)} stroke="black" />
    {data.map((item, idx) => (
      <rect 
        key={idx}
        x={xScale(item.date) - 10}
        width={20}
        y={yScale(0)}
        height={yScale(item.value)}
        fill="blue"
      />
    ))}
  </svg>
)
}
```

I typed this from memory so it might not actually work, but basically it should be drawing a bar chart with a timeline as the x-axis. Using d3 with vanilla js is useful because it can handle keeping track of the data points and drawing svg elements accordingly, but this sort of task is also one of the things React is good at, and in my opinion is easier to read.

Comment: Graphs simple like that aren't a problem.
The problem is that my graphs are slightly more complicated than this example:
https://www.iso.org/obp/graphics/std//iso_std_iso_230-7_ed-2_v2_en/fig_9.png

Doing this stuff with D3.js on its own is challenging, i'm wondering what would happen by adding React to the formula

Comment: In all honesty, that graph doesn’t look that complex. Is that an equation or a data set? I can try to help you generate it if you can get me some more information.